# Update data in android

Tags: android, sqlite, crud

i'm trying to update data that are already in the database but i get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

and it's in the line 49

looks like this

```
boolean isUpdate = db.updateData(id.getText().toString(), 
username.getText().toString(), name.getText().toString(), 
email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())`
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely pointing to a resource that isn't on the XML file you loaded for the Actvity/Fragment.